# gale shapely many to one matching

Tags: r, matlab

Is there a code available (in matlab or R) for the Gale-shapely many to one algorithm code available in either matlab or r?

i have to run it using the GS module, rather than a bipartite graph through the means of maximising the weight of each edge from two different nodes.

Comment: i tried to google Gale-Shapely codes, but mostly return me one-to-one stable matching, such as

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-December/299312.html

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB File Exchange is a great source to look for these stuff. For example, a simple search would have yielded this [stable matching tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34014-stable-matching).

Comment: Thanks! but this is for one-to-one matching, i am looking for many-to-one matching 

do you know any codes available?

Comment: @LowYiXiang Nope, but it seems that you can modify it to do many-to-one matchings with relative ease. Why not implement it yourself, for the sake of practice? ;) It's not that hard.

Comment: can you give me some advice? 

how should i edit the code while implementing 'qouta'? and in my case i only have 3 colleges? i am trying to show some results computationally. 

for simplicity it is safe to assume that all my colleges have the exact same preferences

Comment: @LowYiXiang How about trying to implement this for yourself, and then post a question if you get stuck? By the way, [here](https://sites.google.com/site/clodoferreira/codes-programming) is another site that holds an implementation for stable matching, and I think it'd serve as a better reference for you.